# What does this typedef declaration do?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers, typedef

I know what typedef does but this statement seems to be puzzling me.

```
typedef int (*funcptr)();
```

This declaration

```
funcptr pf1,pf2
```

Means this

```
int (*pf1)(),(*pf2)();
```

But then how to use `pf1` and `pf2` in program. How to take input of these values.
And what is the use of it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `typedef` defines a type for a function pointer. Taking a "value" of a function pointer has no meaning: it is a pointer to a piece of executable code; you need to call it to make it useful.

You call a function through a pointer in the same way as if it were a function known to you by name, i.e. by appending a parenthesized list of parameters to the pointer.

Here is what you can do with `pf1` or `pf2`:

```
// These functions return an int and take no parameters.
// They are compatible with funcptr
int function5() {
    return 5;
}
int functionAsk() {
    int res;
    printf("Enter a value: ");
    scanf("%d", &res);
    return res;
}
// This function does not know what fp1 does, but it can use it
void doSomething(funcptr fp1) {
    int res = fp1();
    printf("Function returned %d", res);
}
// Here is how you can call doSomething with different function pointers
pf1 = functionAsk;
doSomething(pf1);
pf2 = function5;
doSomething(pf2);
```

Note how in the last four lines two calls of `doSomething` perform different tasks based on what you pass: the first call prompts the user for an entry, while the second call returns five right away.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very artificial example code, but it illustrates how to use `typedef` function pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int (*funcptr)();

int return1(void){return 1;}
int return2(void){return 2;}

int main()
{
    funcptr pf1, pf2;
    pf1 = return1;
    pf2 = return2;
    printf("%d, %d\n", pf1(), pf2());
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `1, 2`

Answer (score 1):

pf1 and pf2 are function pointers now...if you want them to point to a function you should write pf1=yourfunctionname..